# Are dead Community Wiki questions removed?

Tags: support, deleted-questions, community-wiki, community-user

I recently [asked a question over on Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1212577/can-windows-10s-battery-life-notifications-be-disabled), but found a duplicate target that provides an answer to it while I was typing the question. I posted the question and hammered it with Mjolnir as in my opinion it's a duplicate signpost that is necessary.

I didn't change or otherwise attempt to edit the duplicate target's question title as it's a slightly different issue, but with an identical answer.

I therefore want to raise a mod-flag to request that it is converted into Community Wiki (as it's likely that the question will be quickly buried and receive no votes), however I also know that the Community user ('Roomba') automatically cleans up dead questions (no upvotes, no answers), and do not wish my question be deleted as I think it's a valuable duplicate signpost.

Does the Roomba delete Community Wiki questions?

The proposed duplicate target doesn't answer my question as it has no reference to CW's status and how it affects the deletion process.

Comment: As an SU mod, I suspect the request for CWificatin would get some headscratching ([since that's not what a CW is for](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/19/the-future-of-community-wiki/)) and probably be denied.

Comment: What is this "Roomba" you speak of?

Answer (score 3):

Roomba does delete questions closed as a duplicate, but only [after 30 days and with some other conditions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba).

It doesn't exempt CW questions from deletion.

Additionally, as your question isn't actually a collaborative work, it shouldn't be made CW.  CW is a way of indicating that a work is not just the work of that one person, everything else are things that the site does given that information.  CW isn't a tool to get those side effects for other reasons.

Comment: This was a general question with some background as to why I might want it (funny as I've had a duplicate on Stack Overflow deleted by the Roomba before when it had no activity and no votes), ta for cleaning that up too :).

Comment: @cybermonkey The 30-day roomba does not care if it's a duplicate (but only applies if score is <= -1, there may have been a last minute vote you did not notice), only the 9-day roomba does. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/roomba) is a good shortlist of rules.

Comment: It was a while ago, so I'm not actually too sure on its status and how soon it was removed after it was posted, unfortunately. I'm not too bothered about that.